# How to analyze a callback function with ollydbg?

Tags: assembly

I have the following call to a function.

```
      ....
      push eax
      push prog.00401D19
      call dword ptr ds:[&USER32.EnumWindows]
      ....
```

So, as you can see, this is a call to `EnumWindows`. But I would like to analyze the code at `00401D19`. Do you know how to do that in *ollydbg* ?

ps: when I make `00401D19` as my new origin (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Gray <kbd>*</kbd>), then I can not go back to the line after `EnumWindows` because side effects etc. can happen. Therefore, I search a different option.

Comment: ctrl+grey asterisk changes the instruction pointer (EIP) use it only when you want to change EIP  to hop front and and back use **ctrl '+' plus and ctrl '+' minus**  to analyse the Callback use contextmenu->follow or ctrl+g  -> enter address -> ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. Select the `push prog.004013D19` line in OllyDbg and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on your keyboard.
2. Left click anywhere in the disassembly listing in OllyDbg, press <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd> on your keyboard, and enter `004013D19` in the popup window.

Comment: Bonus: press `Esc` to go back to the place you were before

Comment: @AcidShout iirc you are confusing ida with ollydbg in ollydbg **esc** pauses the debugger (equivalent to **f12** key )

Comment: @blabb I just tried it and nope, it works there too. In OllyDbg 2, however, you need to press `NUMPAD-` to go back.